Ubuntu で Docker パッケージのインストール途中で止まってしまう
https://maku.blog/p/8k4j2gw/
に記載の「install-docker.yml」を、
hosts部を自環境のホストグループに変更して実行したところ、
途中で未応答状態となりました。
そのときのログは以下です。TASK[Install Docker]で未応答状態となっています。
Ansibleで、Dockerをインストールするには、
他に変更しなければならないところなどありますでしょうか？
（もしくは、どうすればAnsibleでデバッグできるか、
教えていただけないでしょうか？）
リモートPC（DockerをインストールするPC）のOSのバージョンは、
24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)です。
(venv) sasaki@SasakiWin10Pro:~/workspace/orcas_proj/ansible$ ansible-playbook playbook_docker.yml --ask-become-pass
BECOME password:

PLAY [Dockerインストールのテスト] ****************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ssh_test.wakoku.app]

TASK [Install APT packages to use a repository over HTTPS] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [ssh_test.wakoku.app]

TASK [Create APT's keyrings directory] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ssh_test.wakoku.app]

TASK [Add Docker's official GPG key] *************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [ssh_test.wakoku.app]

TASK [Setup the repository] **********************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [ssh_test.wakoku.app]

TASK [Install Docker] ****************************************************************************************************************************************


質問自体は解決済みのようですが、タイトルは「やりたいこと」ではなく「起きている問題」に絞った方が伝わりやすいケースもあるので参考にしてください。今回の場合なら「リモートPCに対して」はあまり関係なくて、「Ubuntu で Docker パッケージのインストール途中で止まってしまう」など。

ありがとうございます。

自己解決しました。ありがとうございました。
別の日に、再度実行したところ、が正しく動作しました。
(原因は分かりませんが、推測ですが、上記問題が発生したときは、
http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
から、パッケージのダウンロードが遅かったことが影響していたと思います。
もちろんダウンロードが遅いのは私の実行環境に問題があった可能性も含まれています。)
以下、参考です。実際に動作したplaybook.ymlを記載します。

---
- name: Dockerインストールのテスト
  # https://maku.blog/p/8k4j2gw/
  hosts: test
  become: true

  tasks:
    # - name: Install APT packages to use a repository over HTTPS
    #   ansible.builtin.apt:
    #     pkg:
    #       - ca-certificates
    #       - curl
    #       - gnupg
    #       - lsb-release
    #     update_cache: yes
    #     cache_valid_time: 86400 # cache for 1 day

    - name: Ansible開始の時刻表示
      debug:
        msg: "Ansible開始 Date:[{{ansible_date_time.iso8601}}]"

    - name: Create APT's keyrings directory
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: /etc/apt/keyrings
        state: directory

    - name: Add Docker's official GPG key
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
        creates: /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg

    - name: Setup the repository
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: >
          echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
          | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
        creates: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

    - name: Install Docker
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        pkg:
          - docker-ce
          - docker-ce-cli
          - containerd.io
          - docker-compose-plugin
        update_cache: yes

    - name: Start Docker
      ansible.builtin.service:
        name: docker
        state: started  

    - name: Ansible完了の時刻表示
      debug:
        msg: "Ansible完了 Date:[{{ansible_date_time.iso8601}}]"


# ◇実行コマンド
# ansible-playbook playbook_docker2.yml --ask-become-pass


